# How to manipulate datas in struct (C)?

Tags: struct

Hello I have a problem with structs in C. I have a text file where there are numerous flights and their information:
flight code, departure city and destination city.
The exercise asks me to make a struct and save all this info in a struct array (which I did without problems). the array I used is:

```
typedef struct{
char FlightCode[N];
char DepartureCity[N];
char DestinationCity[N];
```

}info;
and the array is declared and filled without problems.

the problem is when i am asked to sort the array in ascending order based on the departure city.  i tried to do a bubble sort like this:

```c
    void BubbleSort(info A[max], int dim){
    int i, j, l=0, r=dim-1;
    info temp[N];
    for (i = l; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = l; j < r-i+l;j++)
        if ((strcmp(A[j].DepartureCity,A[j+1].DepartureCity))>0) {
            temp=A[j];
            A[j]=A[j+1];
            A[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me warning and I'm not sure I can switch data in struct like I'm trying to do therewith temp.
Sorry for my bad English, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please add the warning? It'll make it easier to help!

Comment: Firstly, don't use a struct containing arrays. Make a struct with the data for _one_ flight, and then use an array of those. Secondly, don't reinvent the wheel, as the C standard library already has a perfectly fine sort method built in, `qsort()`